# R: ggplot2: creating a margin with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I am partitioning a scatter plot `p` by a single variable e.g.

```
p = p + facet_wrap(~ DayOfWeek, ncol = 3)
```

Is there a way to include a margin at the end of the graph i.e. a scatter plot which doesn't partition the data by `DayOfWeek`?

Cheers fro any help

Comment: It would help more if you post your data (using `dput` preferably), your entire code to reproduce the same graph to see what you mean more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to append a copy of the data set to itself, with `DayofWeek` set to "all", as follows:

Make up data and base plot:

```
w <- c("Sun","Mon","Tues","Weds","Thurs","Fri","Sat")
f <- data.frame(x=runif(200),y=runif(200),
                DayofWeek=factor(sample(w,size=200,replace=TRUE),levels=w))
library(ggplot2)
p  <- ggplot(f,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
```

Append marginalized data set:

```
fx <- rbind(f,transform(f,DayofWeek="all"))
```

Substitute combined data and facet:

```
p %+% fx + facet_wrap(~DayofWeek,ncol=3)
```